# How to create streaming Beam pipeline that is triggered once and only once in a fixed interval

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

***I need to create an Apache Beam (Java) streaming job that should start once (and only once) every 60 seconds.***

I got it working correctly using DirectRunner by using GenerateSequence, Window, and Combine.

However when I run it on Google Dataflow, sometimes it is triggered more than once within the 60 seconds window. I am guessing it has something to do with delays and out of order messages.

```java
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
pipeline
    // Jenerate a tick every 15 seconds
    .apply("Ticker", GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(15)))
    // Just to check if individual ticks are being generated once every 15 second
    .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<Long, Long>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(@Element Long tick, OutputReceiver<Long> out) {
                ZonedDateTime currentInstant = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Jakarta"));
                LOG.warn("-" + tick + "-" + currentInstant.toString());
                out.output(word);
            }
        }
    ))
    // 60 Second window
    .apply("Window", Window.<Long>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(60))))
    // Emit once per 60 second 
    .apply("Cobmine window into one", Combine.globally(Count.<Long>combineFn()).withoutDefaults())
    .apply("START", ParDo.of(new DoFn<Long, ZonedDateTime>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(@Element Long count, OutputReceiver<ZonedDateTime> out) {
                ZonedDateTime currentInstant = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Jakarta"));
                // LOG just to check
                // This log is sometimes printed more than once within 60 seconds
                LOG.warn("x" + count + "-" + currentInstant.toString());
                out.output(currentInstant);
            }
        }
    ));
```

[image: Double run at 12:46 and 12:48]

It works most of the time, except once every 5 or 10 minutes at random I see two outputs in the same minute. How do I ensure "START" above runs once every 60 seconds? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** you can't currently, Beam model is focused on event-time processing and correct handling of late data.

**Workaround:** you can define a processing-time timer, but you will have to deal with outputs and handling of the timer and late data manually, [see this](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html#processing-time-timers) or [this](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2019/06/11/looping-timers.html).

**More details:**

Windows and triggers in Beam are usually defined in event time, not in processing time. This way if you have late data coming after you already emitted the results for a window, late data still ends up in the correct window and results can be re-calculated for that window. Beam model allows you to express that logic and most of its functionality is tailored for that.

This also means that usually there is no requirement for a Beam pipeline to emit results at some specific real-world time, e.g. it doesn't make sense to say things like - "aggregate the events that belong to some window based on the data in the events themselves, and then output that window every minute". Beam runner aggregates the data for the window, possibly waits for the late data, and then emits results as soon as it deems right. The condition when the data is ready to be emitted is specified by a trigger. But that's just that - a condition when the window data is ready to be emitted, it doesn't actually force the runner to emit it. So the runner can emit it at any point in time after the trigger condition is met and the results are going to be correct, i.e. if more events have arrived since timer condition was met, only the ones that belong to a concrete window will be processed in that window.

Event-time windowing doesn't work with processing-time triggering and there are no convenient primitives (triggers/windows) in Beam to deal with processing time in presence of late data. And in this model if you use a trigger that only fires once, you lose the late data, and you still don't have a way to define a robust processing-time trigger. To build something like that you have to be able to specify things like the real-life point in time from which to start measuring the processing time from, and you will have to deal with issues of different processing time and delays that can happen across a large fleet of worker machines. This just is not part of Beam at the moment.

There are efforts in Beam community that will enable this use case, e.g. [sink triggers](https://s.apache.org/beam-sink-triggers) and [retractions](https://s.apache.org/beam-retractions) that will allow you to define your pipeline in event-time space but remove the need for complex event-time triggers. The results could be either immediately updated/recalculated and emitted, or the trigger can be specified at a sink like "I want the output table to be updated every minute". And the results will be updated and recalculated for late data automatically without your involvement. These efforts are far from completion though at this point, so your best bet currently is either using one of the [existing triggers](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#triggers) or manually handling everything with [timers](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html#processing-time-timers).

Comment: Thanks @anton, I understand its difficult (or impossible) to window on the processing time. But would it be possible to window on event time and generate the `Combine` output once and only once for the events (i.e. GenerateSequence) in event time? (It's ok to either ignore or wait for a fixed seconds but emit the window only once for a given 60 seconds interval. Out of order is also ok.)